# Google Maps KML of California Outline

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, kml, kmz

Trying to find a good resource on KML files for outlines of individual states (specifically CA), or how to generate the file—but am running short on my searches. Any pointers appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option would be to extract the `<Placemark>` for California from the `USA_adm1.kmz` file (adm level 1 is states) from http://www.gadm.org/

[california kml on a google maps API v3 map](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_GoogleEx_layer-kml_linktoB.html?filename=http://www.geocodezip.com/geoxml3_test/kml/California.kml)

Comment: Much appreciated. So to use this as a layer so that the map will show only California, I would do something like this?
`var ctaLayer = new google.maps.KmlLayer({
     url: 'url/California.kml',
     map: map
   });
`

Answer (score 0):

Census Tiger provides boundaries in KML:
   https://www.census.gov/geo/maps-data/data/tiger-kml.html

You would have to extract and serve them up from your own server - which is reasonable.